# Temporary download folder Firefox macOS (10.13)

Tags: macos, firefox

I use Firefox(ver 115) on macOS (10.13). I recently changed the setting to save downloaded files to tmp dir by default `browser.download.start_downloads_in_tmp_dir`.

Then I found Firefox download folder is relocated to `/var/folders/…` by default.

My question is whether the files in this location will be deleted automatically by FF or by system, if anybody knows how long the self-cleansing process takes? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Browsers tend to move temp downloads as soon as they're complete. If your temp location is your actual downloads directory, you will see this happen 'live'.

The best way to check for your new location is really to to open the folder & watch it happen. Sort by Date Created, or Modified & it will be easier to find.

`var/folders` is a bit of a nightmare to navigate otherwise & received wisdom is to not play in there manually. On later macOS, the system won't even let you play in there, but High Sierra doesn't have the same protection - it will let you break things if you're not careful.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I can find the downloads in var/folders. No problem. I wonder if these files will be removed automatically afterwards. Sometimes I need to check many pdf files online, but I don't need to save all of them in my normal download folder. I am hoping all the downloads can be wiped out automatically after a period of time and I can manually move the ones I need to save to a different location.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I found the downloads in var/folders were wiped out automatically after I restarted computer. So it is what I wanted to see~